# For loop running twice (object inside of an array)

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, object

I am tying to build a todo list.

The part that fills the list as the user enters something and chooses a date is this:

```
const renderToDoList = () => {

    displayStuffJS.innerHTML = ''
    for (let i = 0; i <= toDoList.length - 1; i ++){

        
        let toDoObject = toDoList[i];
        let input = toDoObject.input
        let date = toDoObject.date
        html = `<p style = 'display: inline-block;'>` + input + date +
        '<button onclick = "deleteEntry(' + i + ')">Delete</button> + </p>';
        displayStuffJS.innerHTML += HTML;
         
           

        }
    }
```

The array (which has an object inside) is having data put into it here:

```
const pushToList = () => {


        displayStuffJS.innerHTML = "";
        toDoList.push([{
            input: inputValue.value, // the input where they put their entry
            date: getDate.value // the value of the date chosen

        }])
        inputValue.value =""; 
        getDate.value = "";


        renderToDoList();
    }
```

When I run this code, enter something, choose a date and click add, it shows me that two loops have occurred, filling the array with two objects, the first object being '' for both input and date, the second index in the array is an object with the input and date I select.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1uc1.png)

it also brings up two delete buttons, but when I click them both they work and delete everything.

pretty stuck now, been on this for an hour and nothing I do works. I have only been programming on and of for a few weeks.

I tried several random things but nothing worked.

Comment: Please post your HTML also and provide a [mre], preferably as a Stack Snippet.

Comment: dont see 2 loops in what you posted. Post your actual HTML, create a working snippet, not images

Answer (score 1):

You are pushing an array with an object inside instead of just pushing the object directly into the toDoList array. This is why you end up with two objects in the array.

```js
const pushToList = () => {
  displayStuffJS.innerHTML = "";
  toDoList.push({
    input: inputValue.value,
    date: getDate.value
  });
  inputValue.value = "";
  getDate.value = "";
  renderToDoList();
}
```

This should resolve the issue.